# while loop only executes subscriber callback()

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the key code parts:

```
def callback(data):
    global value
    value = data.data

def listener():
    #init.node and creating a subscriber for a topic are performed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        print('inside main')
        rospy.spin()
```

My problem is that the print statement 'inside main' is executed only once and I don't understand why, shouldn't it be looping for as long as the rospy is up and running? However, after rospy.spin() the callback() function is executed constantly, but the print statement is not repeated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310291/while-loop-only-executes-subscriber-callback()/) by [Elona](https://answers.ros.org/users/28756/elona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
> ```

```
    listener()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        print('inside main')
        rospy.spin()
```

> My problem is that the print statement 'inside main' is executed only once and I don't understand why, shouldn't it be looping for as long as the rospy is up and running?

No, it shouldn't.

`rospy.spin()` is a blocking call: you're program will not advance to the next line as long as `rospy.spin()` is executing -- which will be forever by design. That is, until you make `rospy.is_shutdown()` true (by using `ctrl+c` for instance).

So your `while` is entered, the `print(..)` statement is executed once and then `rospy.spin()` takes over and never returns.

---

Edit: some things to note:

- `rospy.spin()` doesn't really do anything: it just sits there, waiting. It's not needed in `rospy` for handling events.
- if you're going to use something else instead of `rospy.spin()`, make sure to properly throttle your `while`-loop, or it will start using 100% cpu even while doing nothing.
- you seem to be implementing a synchronous sampling system (`global value; value = data.data`): you may want to consider handling incoming msgs directy in the callback and keep everything event-based, or take a look at [message_filters/Cache](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Cache).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3